# LiveSDK: C# how to get file size before downloading

Tags: c#, file, size, live-sdk

I was wondering to how to get file size from Skydrive before dowloading so that app may decide to to download or not according to the file size.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the type of implementation you are doing it differs. A good guide on how to access the information of files on SkyDrive you can read _[the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#reading_files_props)_.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Live.DynamicDictionary has everything I wanted. The dictionary has the key for "size".

Here are all 16 keys

- id
- from
- name
- description
- parent_id
- size
- upload_location
- comments_count
- comments_enabled
- is_embeddable
- count
- link
- type
- shared_with
- created_time
- updated_time

Answer (score 0):

Like Sander said obtaining the size of the file may differ depending on your type of implementation. For me I use HttpClient requests and responses. Once I get a response from the skydrive I can read the number of bytes within the contents of the file before downloading it and give the file size information to the user before starting the download.

Comment: Thank you both, Andrew and Sander, for replies!